# Memory representation of values in Lisp

Tags: lisp

I read that in original lisp, CONS represented in memory in 36 bits, 18 first bits are for CAR (15 bits are address and 3 bits tells if it is address of ATOM or another CONS), and the latter 18 bits are for the CDR (15 bits...). My question is what is the representation of the ATOM addressed if it need more then one byte, for example for string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Lisp" is a *family* of languages, not a single language.  Many languages in the family (e.g., Common Lisp) don't specify the internal representations, but rather the contract that the structures and functions have to preserve.  In the case of **cons**, it's roughly the equations:

```
(car (cons x y)) == x
(cdr (cons x y)) == y
```

and the requirement that **cons** returns a new object each time it's called.  In some Lisps, cons cells are immutable, and so the requirement that a new object is returned isn't present.

Of course, there are actually implementations, and they do actually have to store things, and it's not unreasonable to ask how they do that.  In general, it's probably best to think of a **cons** cell as a structure big enough to hold two pointers, and probably some information holding its type (so that it can be recognized as a **cons** cell).  The pointers used by the implementaiton might be tagged, though, so that if, e.g., the first three bits are some special values, the "pointer" can be recognized as the encoding of some primitive value.

The important part here is that you usually don't need to know the underlying representation on the machine, and that in the cases that you do (e.g., if you're writing code to interface with another language (e.g., C)), then the answers that you're looking for are going to be specific to each implementation.

Comment: CONS cells are basic to most Lisps that implementations do special things to optimize the runtimes for them. For example often they are not represented like two element vectors are represented. For example it can be useful to avoid the tag per cons cell by typing the reference to cons cells. It makes no difference on an abstract level, but on the runtime engine level there can be a big difference. I fear Lisp implementation details are kind of off-topic here - unless they create programmer visible effects.

Answer (score 1):

The first LISP didn't have strings. It only had symbols and cons. How the symbol letters were stored was described slightly in the [John McCarthy's paper](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive/node4.html). The letters were encoded 6 bit each making room for 5 in each address. A list (called associated list) put together these so you can have more than 5 letter symbols.

The user never get to touch those structures so how you do it is really not important. I made my own McCarthy Lisp, [Zozotez](http://sylwester.no/zozotez/),  in BrainF*ck and encoded my symbol names as a `cons` where `car` always was a ascii value and `cdr` either was a new cons with a letter or `NIL`.

PS: Modern Lisps have characters as a primitive type, similar to symbols. A String is a sequence of characters. Common Lisp use one dimentional arrays(=vectors) with special type to distinguish strings from other arrays and require these to have elements of characters. Like other vectors and lists you cannot just compare as value but either use string predicates or `equal` and `equalp` that will compare the parts of a sequence.

Comment: Who is this McCharty? Strings in something like Common Lisp are vectors and not lists.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Better? It doesn't matter if it's lists or vectors really since I just wanted to point out that they were sequences and not primitive objects. And yeah, better learn to write the name of my hero correct :-)

Comment: “Who is this McCharty?" reads a bit like "Who are those Kernighan and Ritchie?" would in a C question ^^

Comment: @spectras Rainer probably knows him better than me. Being scandinavian I find writing Ole-Johan Dahl and Kristen Nygaard less difficult than John McCarthy. I literally have to look it up each time :-p

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly a cons cell referencing a symbol just contains a pointer to some structure that describes it. So EQ can be implemented as a pointer comparison. The three additional bits are used to keep some type information, so that even FIXNUMS can be coded and compared this way.